# Can pandas auto recognize if header is present

Tags: python, pandas

pandas beginner here,

I read that `pandas.read_csv` automatically assumes that the first column is a header column, and if this is not the case, I should pass a flag, `header=None`.

Now I have a code which loads CSVs which sometimes have headers and sometimes not... Is there a way or a flag to `read_csv` to try and automatically detect a header row?

If a column (or several) has numbers in all rows except the first - then it's a header row, otherwise no headers.

Comment: Based on your last statement, you can grab the first row of each csv, check the logic and set `header` accordingly

Comment: I could, for some reason I thought pandas has this functionality built-in somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so quick (and probably fragile) idea:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ints_only", "strings_only"],
                  data=[[1,"a"], [3,"b"]])

df.to_csv("header.csv")
df.to_csv("noheader.csv", header=None)


def has_header(file, nrows=20):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, nrows=nrows)
    df_header = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=nrows)
    return tuple(df.dtypes) != tuple(df_header.dtypes)


has_header("header.csv")    # gives True
has_header("noheader.csv")  # gives False
```

What's happening here?

We read the first nrows (default 20) lines of the csv file. One time with header and one time without. Then we look at what datatypes pandas assigns to each column. If the datatypes don't change when ignoring the first row, then there is no header (that of course only works if you always at least one column where the header is a string, but at least some of the values are of one other datatype that is not a string, e.g. float).

Comment: I like your solution, will try it!

(I think you should first declare `df = pd.DataFrame...` and then proceed, but it's OK i git the idea)

Comment: oh yeah, the order of these statements was wrong. I updated it ;)

Answer (score 0):

When the dataframe has no header its `Dataframe.columns` property employs numerical indexes. Otherwise, it uses strings. So, just check the type of the first column label.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

def has_header(df):
    return isinstance(df.columns[0], str)

csv=u"""col1,col2,col3
5,2,7
4,9,6
7,3,1"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))
print(df1.head())
if has_header(df1):
    print("Dataframe 1 has header")
else:
    print("Dataframe 1 doesn't have header")

csv=u"""5,2,7
4,9,6
7,3,1"""

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), header=None)
print(df2.head())
if has_header(df2):
    print("Dataframe 2 has header")
else:
    print("Dataframe 2 doesn't have header")

df3= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))
print(df3.head())
if has_header(df3):
    print("Dataframe 3 has header")
else:
    print("Dataframe 3 doesn't have header")

df4 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), header='infer')
print(df4.head())
if has_header(df4):
    print("Dataframe 4 has header")
else:
    print("Dataframe 4 doesn't have header")
```

Here is the output produced by the above code.

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     5     2     7
1     4     9     6
2     7     3     1
Dataframe 1 has header
   0  1  2
0  5  2  7
1  4  9  6
2  7  3  1
Dataframe 2 doesn't have header
   5  2  7
0  4  9  6
1  7  3  1
Dataframe 3 has header
   5  2  7
0  4  9  6
1  7  3  1
Dataframe 4 has header
```

Please note that when using `pd.read_csv` to create your `Dataframe` you have to explicitly set `header=None`. Otherwise, the column names are inferred from the first line of the file (see [pasntas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)).

Answer (score -1):

You may use

**str** and **contains**

```
df['column_name'].str.contains('text_you_are_expecting_in_header')
```

This would return a True/False based on whether the column entries contain what you are looking for.

Thereafter, you may read off the first entry (for your header row), and if it matches the text you expect in your header, then you have a header, else you don't have a header.

Comment: I don't know column names in advance, this module can be used for different data files...